# How to Make Kotlin Gradle Plugin not Manage Version

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I use Kotlin Gradle Plugin and consume Kotlin BOM at the same time it seems that the plugin version takes in priority for `kotlin-stdlib`, how do I make the plugin not manage my dependency?

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.50"
}

dependencies {
        implementation(platform("some-bom:0.3")) // this has API dependency to kotlin-bom 1.3.50
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib")) // this resolves to 1.2.50 (plugin version) instead of 1.3.50 (BOM version)
}
```

Project is using Gradle 5.2.1

Comment: What gradle version are you using?

Comment: This is reproducible in 5.2.1

Comment: Please attach output of dependencies gradle command

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it, it looks like a bug. As a workaround you can [enforce](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version) a particular version by specify `isForce = true`:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.50") {
    isForce = true
}
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.10"){
   isForce = true
}
```

`isForce` is not transitive, so you have to specify all the transitive kotlin dependencies explicitly with `isForce` flag true or create a [virtual platform](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#declaring_participation_in_a_platform):

```
open class KotlinAlignmentRule : ComponentMetadataRule {
    override fun execute(ctx: ComponentMetadataContext) {
        ctx.details.run {
            if (id.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") {
                belongsTo("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-platform:${id.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add it to your dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    components.all(KotlinAlignmentRule::class.java)
    implementation(platform("some-bom:0.3")) 
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.50") {
        isForce = true
    }
}
```

This last solution is the best imo.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question a bit, I don't want to override the BOM. _the Kotlin plugin_ is overriding my BOM without my control and I want to stop it

Comment: Oh, indeed, I could have read the question more carefully. Could you attach output of `dependencies` gradle command?